# Query to differentiate between stock and in saleorder

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.  Table A contains one column Priority.  Table B contains Priority, Lot and salesorder.

**Table A**

```
Priority
--------
122
123
124
```

**Table B**

```
Priority |  Lotid   | salesorderline
--------------------------------
122        |  14257  |      4   
122        |  14528  |      6  
122        |  14782  |      4  
122        |  14587  |      0
```

I'm expecting results like:

```
Priority | TotalLot | salesorder | In Stock
-------------------------------------------
     122 |        4 |          3 |        1
```

If salesorderline is greater than 0 than its a salesorder otherwise stock

Comment: As an advisory, you should redesign your database schema - row semantics shouldn't be overloaded like this.

Comment: @EoinS Table A is the master table I have just showed you the scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for each Priority in `Table A` (which I'll call `Priorities`) you want aggregate data on each row group in `Table B` (`Lots`)?

There are multiple ways to build this query. The simplest is a single query with predicated aggregate functions:

```
SELECT
    Lots.Priority,
    COUNT(*) AS TotalLots,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SalesOrderLine  > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS SalesOrder,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SalesOrderLine <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS InStock
FROM
    Lots
    INNER JOIN Priorities ON Priorities.Priority = Lots.Priority
   -- this JOIN doesn't do anything because the Priorities table does not contain any useful data at this point
GROUP BY
    Priority
ORDER BY
    Priority ASC
```

Note that I feel your database design is not correct - I don't see why row  `SalesOrder`/`Lot` row should represent how something is in stock or not, and overloading the `SalesOrderLine` to give it meaning is a bad design.